# nestedScrollingEnabled not working in AppBarLayout

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-coordinatorlayout, android-appbarlayout

I have a horizontal recyclerview inside the AppBarLayout, which is inside the CoordinatorLayout, which is inside the SwipeRefreshLayout. I want that when I move horizontally in recyclerview it can't if the user accidentally pulls down to do a refresh. I tried nestedScrollingEnabled = false, but it doesn't help

Comment: Please attach the code of what you have tired

Comment: For debugging questions like this, a [mre] would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Take the horizontal recyclerview out of the appbar layout. then set this code for swipe refresh layout:

```
appbarDetails.addOnOffsetChangedListener(AppBarLayout.OnOffsetChangedListener { appBarLayout, verticalOffset ->
            swipeRefresh.isEnabled = verticalOffset == 0
        })
```

swipe refresh it is only active when the screen is on top